# Crystal report has login failed error after enable 32-bit application to true in the application pool on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

My web application’s target CPU is ANYCPU. On IIS   that application pool, I need to set enable 32-Bit Application to be true because of referencing another interop dll. After changing, the crystal report has login failed error. It works when the setting of enable 32-bit to be false. 
On web server, I installed SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(32-bit). Also it has installed SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(64-bit). 
The dll files of Crystal report is reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll

Would anyone can tell me how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the 32-bit runtime of Crystal on the Server.